# Box with multiple borders

Tags: html, css, border

I am trying to code and style a box which will contain a post. My problem is with multiple borders (i guess), trying to find the best way to code this, i prefer semantic HTML5 and CSS3, but if there is no other way, i can do "old style" with 3 divs (top, center, bottom) with css background: url..., can anyone give me some lights please?

If you please check the following url, you can check what i need to accomplish.

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3696224/postBox.jpg

If you notice it has:

- one border around all the box with a dark gray (#cccccc); (border)
- a small space between that border and other light gray (#f7f7f7), almost white;
- and only then the content with a white background;

Any suggestions? Very sorry for English grammar, thanks in advance.

Regards

PS - I almost forgot, i don't know is if needed or not, but the all around the box i have a box-shadow (i know how to do this part)

Comment: It could be done with one with `:after` and similar.

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks, :after is compatible with major browsers? I tried before but i didn't the result that i need.

Comment: compatible with all recent browsers and much neater HTML too :-)  I got it working, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need 2 different `<div>` elements; one for each border that you want.

#### HTML

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        CONTENT
    </div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
/* colors sampled from image linked in OP */

.outer {
    border: 1px solid #C8C8C8;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px #000;
}

.inner {
    background-color: #FFF;
    border: 5px solid #F8F8F8;
    color: #595959;
    padding: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

[`z0mg` demo →](http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/u7SgE/1/)

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks for suggestion, sincerely i don't know how i forgot this :), its logic, you only forgot the margin for the small space, but i already did that. Thanks again for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using no messy markup. See this in action at http://jsfiddle.net/7xGKk/.

This should work properly in Firefox 3.5+, Safari 4+, Chrome 4+, Opera 10+ and Internet Explorer 8+.  Others will get a 7px outside-colour border; if you wished to change the colour of the three selected you could remove the `.fancyframe` `background-color` and modify z-indicies, e.g. to make #f7f7f7 the border.

This plays nicely with `box-shadow` etc; the border is contained inside the div.

HTML:

```
<div class="fancyframe">content</div>
```

CSS:

```
.fancyframe {
    background-color: white;
    border: 7px solid #cccccc;
    position: relative;
    /* The rest of this block is purely stylistic to make it look precisely
       like the original image except for font. */
    padding: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    line-height: 4em;
    font-size: 50px;
    width: 492px;
    font-family: Impact, sans-serif;
    color: #595959;
}
.fancyframe:before {
    content: "";
    margin: -6px;
    position: absolute;
    border: 6px solid #ffffff;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.fancyframe:after {
    content: "";
    margin: -5px;
    position: absolute;
    border: 5px solid #f8f8f8;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Man you rock! Really appreciate, thanks a lot, works like a charm :). But i have a problem, if you know how i can fix it, if i have floated elements inside the content it crash. I already clear the floats after the .fancyframe but it did not work. Thanks again.

Comment: I forgot to say, i have problems selecting text and clicking in the links too, do you know why? If you want i can send you a link with what i have been testing.

Comment: @Mambley: if you have floating elements inside it you'll need to make sure they are cleared inside it too; a "clearfix" is the standard name for this. However, due to already using `:after` the standard CSS hacks (`:after` content or `overflow: hidden`) won't work, so I believe you're reduced to needing a `<br style="clear: both">` or similar (if your existing last child element doesn't float you could also put it on it, `.fancyframe > :last-child { clear: both; }` may work, depends on what you've got in there).

Comment: @Mambley: concerning selecting the contents of it... sorry, that's an aspect I hadn't thought about; that's something I can't think of a solution for at the moment. The inner div technique may be the only practical way of doing it if you need the contents inside to be accessible.

Comment: thanks for the explanation, since i need to float some elements inside and also need to select/click in the content i will use the inner div technique. Anyway i will keep your solution for future reference, thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use -moz-border-top-colors property for the same.
I tested this on Mozilla and it works
You can play with the code at given link.

```css
div{
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    border-top:10px solid red;
   
-moz-border-top-colors: red red red green green green yellow yellow;

    
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.postcbox {
  border: 1px #ccc solid;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
}

.postbox {
  background-color: white;
}


<div class="postcbox">
  <div class="postbox">

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `box-shadow` property, the good thing about `box-shadow` is that we can have as many of them as we want, comma separated:

```
box-shadow:0 0 0 10px #655,
            0 0 0 15px deeppink,
            0 2px 5px 15px; rgba(0,0,0,.6);
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nqLjpL6x/)